# Uploading multiple files using jquery file uploader and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am working on a web application in php mysql.Here,the requirement says,that the user should be able to upload more than one files at a time,to store them on server.Currently I can upload a single file using this,

```
 $(function(){
var btnUpload=$("#uploadPdf");
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
    action:"uploadPdf.php",
    name: "uploadCertPdf",
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){
         if (!(ext && /^(pdf)$/.test(ext))){ 
            alert("Upload File (Supports PDF formats only)");
            return false;
        }           
        var stats = $("#resultsOuter");
        stats.html('<img src="images/layout/preloader-2.png" />');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
            alert(response);
            alert("File uploaded successfully");
            window.location="somePage.php";

    }
  })
  });        

 /**somePage.php file**/

  if (isset($_FILES["uploadCertPdf"]))
  {
  if ($_FILES["uploadCertPdf"]["error"] > 0)
  {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["uploadCertPdf"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
       if(!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."admin/pdf/"))
     {  echo "not found";
        mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."admin/pdf/", 0777,true);
     } 
         if(file_exists($file))
        {   echo "duplicate";
            $flag = TRUE;
        }
        else
        { 
            $uploaddir = '/admin/pdf/';
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadCertPdf']['name']);
            $path_info = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadCertPdf']['name']);
            $type= $path_info['extension']; 
            if($type == 'pdf')
            {   

                $flag = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadCertPdf']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile);

            }else{
                echo "You can upload only PDF files";
                }
        }

      }
   }
```

How can I customize it to upload multiple files at a time?I tried to search,but all plugins are customized to use some user interface,i.e they have their own independent modules and functionalities.
So,any help with this would be appreciated.Thanks for the time.
**EDIT:** I am adding the ajax uploader function that creates a file input dynamically.

```
    /**
 * Creates invisible file input above the button 
 **/
_createInput : function(){
    var self = this;
    var input = d.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('name', this._settings.name);
    input.setAttribute('id', 'file'+this._settings.name);
    var styles = {
        'position' : 'absolute'
        ,'margin': '-5px 0 0 -175px'
        ,'padding': 0
        ,'width': '220px'
        ,'height': '30px'
        ,'fontSize': '14px'                             
        ,'opacity': 0
        ,'cursor': 'pointer'
        ,'display' : 'none'
        ,'zIndex' :  2147483583 //Max zIndex supported by Opera 9.0-9.2x 2147483583 
        // Strange, I expected 2147483647   
    };
```

I tried by adding an array to the name attribute,but did not work.

Comment: check this link http://fineuploader.com/ it may help you

Comment: Use plupload. It has lots of options available. http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: Thanks for the responses,but I am not looking for a plugin bcoz I am already using one and dont have enough time to switch to another as I already have it working at different places.Hence I wanted someone to identify the changes needed to modify my plugin to the multiple upload scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery Plugin available at http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ for multiple file upload at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I just completed a multi-file upload functionality on a Grails project, using this article as a guide (which is based on PHP). If you want to roll your own - it's a great reference.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: Yes I have tried something similar,but the issue is I am not using the traditional upload button.I am using jquery ajax for uploading the file and it dyanamically handles the upload using an **iframe**. Now,when the upload dialog box opens it does not allow me to select multiple files.Even though I have added the name attribute as an array(similar to what is done in the link you suggested). Thanks

Comment: The example in the article actually does multiple file uploads using pure ajax (jQuery) - it only defaults to traditional single upload in the case of IE9 and below. Otherwise the code in the example allows a user to select multiple files and on "change" event, it uploads all the selected files.

Comment: Will go through and give it a try!Thanks!